# Undo Feature in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, undo

I want to add a 'Undo' feature to my application which removes the last entered number into a field.
This is what I got so far

```
      private void btnUndo(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:


    final UndoManager manager = new UndoManager();

    if (evt.getActionCommand().equals("Undo")) {

        try {
            manager.undo();
        } catch (CannotUndoException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



}
```

Any Ideas? (I have no idea if this is right or not)

Thanks

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076698/core-java/add-an-undo-redo-function-to-your-java-apps-with-swing.html

Comment: Another example at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextComponentDemoProject/src/components/TextComponentDemo.java , explained in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#undoredoactions , and already working on text documents. If this is not what you are looking for, you might want to point out why you asked specifically for *numbers* that are entered...

Comment: If you want to do that in the right way, there's a design pattern that  it's used for that, here's a a tutorial about Command Design Pattern http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-command . For each number the user inserts you just encapsulate it in a command, and since you can keep tracking on the executed commands, you can undo

Comment: I guess UndoManager is based on Command Design Pattern

Answer (score 1):

See example of UndoManager

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Undomanager.htm

Java Docs :-http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/UndoManager.html